# Changing string to avoid duplication in a systematic manner?

Tags: python

Take the list `Usernames` as shown below.

```
Usernames = ["johnsmith"]
```

I have the variable `NewUsername` and I need to check if its value is already contained in the list. If not, an integer will be concatenated to the end of it.

Examples:

```
NewUsername = "alexsmith"
Usernames = ["johnsmith", "alexsmith"]

NewUsername = "johnsmith"
Usernames = ["johnsmith", "alexsmith", "johnsmith1"]

NewUsername = "johnsmith"
Usernames = ["johnsmith", "alexsmith", "johnsmith1", "johnsmith2"]
```

Now, I know I can do this with something like this, but it would only check for the first 'level' of duplicate names.

```
if NewUsername in Usernames:
    NewUsername = NewUsername + "1"
Usernames.append(NewUsername)
```

**Question:** How can I handle all duplications in a similar manner?

Comment: Use a dictionary `<str, int>` where int was the last value you appended, keep increasing int as necessary

Comment: You can use `dict<str,list>` in case you want to remove any element at later stage

Comment: @MitchelPaulin example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is a bit elaborate, but you could use a custom child class of a list. To give you an idea:

```
from collections import Counter

class UsernameList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(UsernameList, self).__init__()
        self._ucount = Counter()
        for e in args[0]:
            self.append(e)

    def append(self, el):
        if isinstance(el, str):            
            if self._ucount[el] == 0:
                super(UsernameList, self).append(el)
            else:
                fixel = el + str(self._ucount[el])
                super(UsernameList, self).append(fixel)
                self._ucount.update([fixel])
            self._ucount.update([el])
        else:
            raise TypeError("Only string can be appended")
```

Now you could do:

```
Usernames = UsernameList(["johnsmith"]) #Username is ["johnsmith"]
Usernames.append("johnsmith") #Username becomes ["johnsmith", "johnsmith1"]
Usernames.append("johnsmith") #Username becomes ["johnsmith", "johnsmith1", "johnsmith2"]
```

Apart the new `__init__` and `append` methods, `UsernameList` has all the methods of a list, and works exactly as a list. Don't bother about the counter attribute, it's there to keep track of the usernames inputed and add the correct number in case of repetitions.
To have something more consistent you may need to override other methods: i'm just giving you an idea, far from writing a full working code here.
You may have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) for more details on which methods you may need to override.